# How do I store large volumes or data points (temperature and humidity points)?

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to use Drupal as a headless API, and so far I'm having good results. One of the things I'm collecting is a Temperature and Humidity data. Thus far I've created an entity that can hold the data points, but now that I'm really thinking about it, this is not the most efficient way of doing this, a new entity has to be created for each datapoint. I've contemplated separating off this part of the api, but then I loose all of the Drupal functionality.

Is there a better way to store large sets of data points using Drupal?
Perhaps I can group the data points within a single field as a JSON string.

Comment: you can post your avance?

Comment: depending on the data structure, you could easily create a custom module to store raw data, without the need or overhead of using entities or even fields

Comment: @Geoff i am referencing some other fields ... date, user Id, would generating a new table with a custom module effect the use of these fields?

Comment: it entirely depends on how you are referencing them - a proper answer beyond the usual entity/node/fields which you seem already well versed in, would require significantly more information - exactly what your tracking, how that data relates to one another, etc. By the sounds of it though, in the end, what you have is probably fully sufficient - unfortunately, there's no guarantee that something custom will be more efficient that the built-in

Answer (score 0):

This is a large topic, so I will just mention some points and you can make the rest.

You will need a module, so you must have a `.info`, `.module` and in your case a `.install` file.

In the `.module` file:

- Implement [hook_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7) to tell Drupal about your custom field. Here is an [example of how to use hook_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example%21field_example.module/function/field_example_field_info/7).
- You must also introduce a widget and a formatter for your field. The widget is what appears in forms when you want to get data from user, and the formatter outputs data in proper way in view modes.
- You need to notify Drupal about these items existence, [hook_field_widget_info](https://api.drupal.org/hook_field_widget_info) and [hook_field_formatter_info](https://api.drupal.org/hook_field_formatter_info) will do the job for you.
- After that you must make your widget, [hook_field_widget_form](https://api.drupal.org/hook_field_widget_form) is the proper hook here and [hook_field_formatter_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/.../hook_field_formatter_view/7) will handle your field view.
- Another thing is a zero function for your field - this function tells Drupal if the user has not filled or passed any data to your widget, [hook_field_is_empty](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_is_empty/7) is implemented for that and it is required, else after form submission your users will face an error.
- [hook_field_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_validate/7) can also be used to validate the data which is entered.

At this point we are done with the `.module` file,  but we still have on more step to go: the `.install` file.

- Here we define a place for data to be stored in DB, [hook_field_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) will do the job for you.

After this point you are all done.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Drupal is not that great at this sort of task.  The right approach depends a lot on what other parts of the Drupal ecosystem you need the data to interact with.

- How do you need to query the data? (single field with JSON string is not going to be conducive to this!)
- Do you need Views integration?
- Do you want to use any of the various input widgets or field formatters?
- Will other content in Drupal need to relate to this data?

Anyhow, even without answers to those questions, I would point you in the direction of the Data module as a possible solution https://www.drupal.org/project/data

It will let you store your data in straightforward tables but provide you with some nice Drupal conveniences.